# getting started with libGDX - project generator is failing to build

Tags: java, android, gradle, libgdx

I'm trying to use the gdx-setup.jar program to generate a libGDX project. The destination of my sdk is configured properly, I've specified sub projects as Android and Desktop and selected IDEA to generate IntelliJ project files for use with Android studio.

When I click generate, libgdx tells me that the project failed to build. The exact output is below:

Generating app in C:\Users\Danial\Documents\Java Android\test
Executing 'C:\Users\Danial\Documents\Java Android\test/gradlew.bat clean --no-daemon idea'
To honour the JVM settings for this build a new JVM will be forked. Please consider using the daemon: https://docs.gradle.org/5.4.1/userguide/gradle_daemon.html.
Daemon will be stopped at the end of the build stopping after processing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- What went wrong:
  Task 'idea' not found in root project 'test'.
- Try:
  Run gradlew tasks to get a list of available tasks. Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.
- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 1m 4s
Done!
To import in Eclipse: File -> Import -> General -> Existing Projects into Workspace
To import to Intellij IDEA: File -> Open -> YourProject.ipr

Comment: I think your project is generated and it simply failed at its initial Gradle build. Try opening your root build.gradle in IDEA and see if the issue persists.

Answer (score 1):

The same error. I juse ignore it and open the project in IDE (android studio), it will sync automatically.

QA:

> New Gradle Sync is not supported due to containing Kotlin modules using an unsupported plugin version

Go to `File - Settings - Kotlin Compiler - Target JVM Version`, set to `1.8`.

> No Desktop launch option

Follow the [official tutorial](https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Gradle-and-Intellij-IDEA#running-your-project) to add a Configuration.